# Aligning words of 2 very similar texts / strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting, subtitle

I have 2 texts that are very similar and I would like to align them word for word.

Text 1

```
I am very grateful you came. Could you help me move the sofa to the living room? Thanks a lot.
```

Text 2

```
I am very happy you came. Could you help me move the sofa to the banana? Thanks a lot.
```

Sometimes the words are just different, but the sentence will have the same amount of words. However, sometimes that's not the case. So I cannot simply split the texts and map through them, since sometimes there will be 2 words in text 1 where there is only 1 word in text 2 and vice versa. (living room => banana).

In the end, I'd like to have an object like this:

```
[
 { 
  text1: "I",
  text2: "I"
 },
 { 
  text1: "am",
  text2: "am"
 },
 { 
  text1: "very",
  text2: "very"
 },
 ...
 {
  text1: "living room",
  text2: "banana
 },
 ...
]
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/difflib

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using the [PatienceDiff](https://github.com/jonTrent/PatienceDiff) algorithm, which I ported to Javascript a while back.  In your specific case, the setup involves splitting the two sentences into arrays of words...

(When you "Run code snippet", press either the "Diff" or "DiffPlus" buttons to see the results of comparing the two sentences...)

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jonTrent/PatienceDiff/PatienceDiff.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="init()">
<script type="text/javascript">

var aLines = `I am very grateful you came. Could you help me move the sofa to the living room? Thanks a lot.`;
var bLines = `I am very happy you came. Could you help me move the sofa to the banana? Thanks a lot.`;

function init() {
  document.getElementById("aLines").value = aLines;
  document.getElementById("bLines").value = bLines;
}

function calcDiff(diffVsPlus) {
  var a = document.getElementById("aLines").value.split(" ");
  var b = document.getElementById("bLines").value.split(" ");
  if (diffVsPlus) {
    var diff = patienceDiff(a , b);
  } else {
    var diff = patienceDiffPlus(a , b);
  }
  
  var diffLines = "";
  diff.lines.forEach((o) => {
    if (o.bIndex < 0 && o.moved) {
      diffLines += "-m  ";
    } else if (o.moved) {
      diffLines += "+m  ";
    } else if (o.aIndex < 0) {
      diffLines += "+   ";
    } else if (o.bIndex < 0) {
      diffLines += "-   ";
    } else {
      diffLines += "    ";
    }
    diffLines += o.line + "\n";
  });
  
  document.getElementById("diff").innerHTML = diffLines;
}

</script>

<div>
<textarea id="aLines" style="width:100%"></textarea><br>
<textarea id="bLines" style="width:100%;"></textarea><br>
<button type="button" onclick="calcDiff(true)">vvv  Diff  vvv</button>
<button type="button" onclick="calcDiff(false)">vvv  DiffPlus  vvv</button><br>
<pre id="diff" style="width:100%; height:500;"></pre>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that in the example above, the sentences were simply split based on the space character.  Thus, periods and other punctuation are included as part of the words.  This might be desirable in some cases (eg, the word "can't") but maybe not in other cases (eg, "lot." includes the period at the end of the sentence).  Depending on the specifics of your use case, you might need to split the sentences using RegExp, which can provide some better control.  Or, another alternative is to preprocess the sentences by removing "." and other potentially unwanted characters, before splitting by the space character...